# Trying to add png files to Midlet project in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, java-me, nokia, midlet

I'm creating a app for nokia using Netbeans v7.  I cannot figure out how to add files to the project, such as graphic images. Also I do not see a res folder like eclipse has.

I'm assuming there must be a way to do this
-Ted

Comment: what language are you using ? Is it j2me or other ?

Answer (score 1):

**Create res** folder in the project folder and put the files in that folder, It's action will be **same as eclipse**.